# Images scales defferently in setImageDrawable() and setImageBitmap()?

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I am new in android development. I have an issue regarding the image scaling in my app. When i set images using setImageDrawable() images look proper like in screenshot:

[image]

But if i  set image using setImageBitmap() method it does not look proper. Some black color occurs around it like in screenshot bellow:

[image]

I have tried it in multiple applications and i observed that in some applications the image size is becoming smaller than the size ofter setting image through `setImageDrawable()` or `setImageResource()`.
the reason for setting images through `setImageBitmap()` is that i want to set images to the imageviews which are kept in assets folder and not in drawable.

Following is the code i used to create a bitmap and set it to imageview:

```
                        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new Options();
                        opts.inPurgeable = true;

                        try
                        {
                            Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(drawableFolder+"/"+tmpArr[0]),null,opts);
                            view.setImageBitmap(preview_bitmap);

                        }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            LNLog.writeTOErrorToLog(e.getMessage());
                        }
```

So, please can anyone tell me where i'm i going wrong or missing something to set.
I tried to set Options but did not worked.  I want to set images as in first screenshot that is how they looks by using `setImageDrawable()`.
   Thanx in advance.

Note: in screenshots images are referent in text on it only.IF i set hindi images i.e. the images on which text is in hindi language using setImageDrawable() then they looks proper as in like in screen shot one.So , no issue of image files.

Comment: now see ImageView.java sources and take a look into setImageBitmap method https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java line 436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
try
{
   view.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
   int height = view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
   int width = view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
   BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   opts.inPurgeable = true;
   opts.inScaled = true;
   Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open("drawable-mdpi/FAQ_hi_in.png",null,opts);
   Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(preview_bitmap, width, height, true);
   view.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

In this code I have taken the `height` and `width` of **actual image** and then scaled my bitmap to that height and width. Then I converted this `scaled bitmap` to `drawable` and set it into my `ImageView`, thats it.  It resolved my problem of black border around image.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the black borders by using

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true" in xml
```

or

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true) in Java.
```

EDIT:
Then try using drawable only

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(assetManager.open(filePath), null);
view.setImageDrawable(d)
```

Comment: i tried setAdjustViewBounds(true) but did not worked.

Comment: @Mazz Thanx for your help .. I applied the imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true) but it does not seems to work. But suggestion you edited worked.